# World wide electricity network

Tags: climate-change

What if the UN, backed up by all nations would by a huge land from some country, lets say Russia and build there lots of nuclear power plants to power up the entire world?

There will be world wide power grid and the entire planet electricity will be produced in single location.

Why?
The NPT prohibits countries to use and produce nuclear capabilities, so most of the world produce electricity from coal, oil, fuel etc. which are pollutant.

Nowadays that the global warming is humanity issue, cant this idea be carried out?

The revenue from the electricity will be used to form an army to protect this are, world wide scientists will work together.

Sounds utopic thinking that countries around the world will dump their power plants and drop the pollution amounts they produce.

Comment: The NPT absolutely **does not** prohibit anybody from building atomic power plants. Many countries have atomic power plants without also having atomic bombs. (And atomic power plants are great as baseload generators. They absolutely suck at adjusting their output to follow the load. It is very hard to accomodate more than about 50% electric power production from atomic power plants.)

Comment: this question needs clarification. It is not entirely clear what you are asking (review)

Comment: It's also worth noting that while central power generation makes sense on a semi-local scale, it makes _much less sense_ globally.  You lose power to line drop the further from a generative source you are, even with HVDC lines.  Noncentralized generation is also less susceptible to single-source failure - a part of the transmission infrastructure failing if the whole world were powered from a single location could blackout an entire country at once.

Comment: (Also, building nuclear power plants takes a lot of time and is more expensive per kwh than solar + batteries, so a prospective UN Power Plan would be much more likely to buy equatorial land than space in Russia.)

Comment: Length of power transmission lines would be an issue. Per [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Electric_power_transmission#Losses), the longest practically viable power transmission line can be 7000 km long.

Comment: Could you give us some background about your fictional world? How does it differ from Earth of today (if at all), what are the incentives to do as you suggested, who's in-charge and what's their propaganda machine like? Why would (say) America allow itself to become a subject country letting Russia control its power?

Comment: VTC:TSB. This is, at best, a [high concept question](https://worldbuilding.meta.stackexchange.com/q/4868/40609), which is off-topic. At worst, it appears to be a real-world question, which is also off-topic. Worldbuilding (on-topic) is about developing and consistently using the rules and systems of a fictional world of your own creation.

Comment: @ARogueAnt. Strictly speaking if the UN *buys* land from Russia, Russia will not be in control of this territory anymore. Russia has the right of veto in the UN, but so are China and the USA. However, I do agree that it is very unlikely that the USA would agree to limited control over its power.

Comment: I think it is a valid question. The OP does not ask how to carry his idea out. They are asking if their idea is feasible.

Comment: Did no one think about using the movements of waves? The Flow of rivers? Wind perhaps? All of those already exist and are used in many countries, such as Brazil. Everyone relying almost exclusively on either fossil fuels to produce energy or on a nuclear reactor that could be on the other side of the planet depending on the country sounds like a very bad decision to make (how much money would it cost to maintain a Gargantuan number of cables, some as long as half of the planet's diameter, to make sure entire countries didn't suffer blackouts? What if war between 2 countries damage them?)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, a global electricity network would increase global warming.

The transmission loss over long distances is significant.  So, a central power generating complex would require more power input than locally generated power.

Also, the carbon footprint of producing solar panels is high enough that it is equivalent to the lifetime carbon footprint of many other methods of power generation.  This is without considering the cost of the batteries.

Also, solar panels degrade over time.  They would have to be replaced every 15 to 20 years.

Nuclear power plants are also not the answer.  Even though they are one of the cheaper per watt solution, have a lower carbon footprint than many other power plants, and are actually very safe (if designed and maintained correctly), there isn't enough fissionable material that is easy to get to on the Earth's crust to power enough plants to serve as the sole source of electricity.

Every type of power generation has its drawbacks.  There are no magic bullets, just some solutions that are slightly better than others.

If we can ever get fusion working, that might do it but in any other scenario, we (and the planet) have to pay the cost to have all our goodies.

Though if you want to cut the world carbon footprint, just know that over half of the world's coal plants are in China.

Comment: There's a lot of misinformation here. [HVDC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/High-voltage_direct_current#Advantages) would almost certainly be used for this, which has very low losses. Lifetime CO2 of solar is less than all fossil fuel sources ([2011 report from World Nuclear](http://www.world-nuclear.org/uploadedFiles/org/WNA/Publications/Working_Group_Reports/comparison_of_lifecycle.pdf)).

Comment: Solar panels don't have to be replaced after 15-20 years, their output just diminishes -- [output will be about 10% less by year 20](https://www.nrel.gov/state-local-tribal/blog/posts/stat-faqs-part2-lifetime-of-pv-panels.html).

Comment: Here's a source about [uranium abundance](https://phys.org/news/2011-05-nuclear-power-world-energy.html) -- you are correct that there's not enough given today's methods, but it's more of a scale problem than a technology issue.